# Troubleshooting if in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am in a very strange powershell behavior.
I have an If, elseif, else.
The If works, The else if works, but the else never happened.

What could it be?

This is the script:

```
$result = Get-AMTHardwareAsset $Computer -credential $VProCredential -textoutput
if ($result.Contains("Unauthorized") -eq $true)
    {
        Add-Results "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-Unauthorized"
    }
elseif ($result.Contains("Could not connect") -eq $true)
    {
        Add-Results "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-CannotConect"
    }

    else
    {
        Add-Results "TESTING"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script to hardcode `$result` to "Fubar", and substituting `Write-Host` for `Add-Results`:

```
$result = 'Fubar'; #Get-AMTHardwareAsset $Computer -credential $VProCredential -textoutput
if ($result.Contains("Unauthorized") -eq $true)
{
    #Add-Results "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-Unauthorized"
    Write-Host "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-Unauthorized"
}
elseif ($result.Contains("Could not connect") -eq $true)
{
    #Add-Results "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-CannotConect"
    Write-Host "$Computer`tHardwareAssets-CannotConect"
}

else
{
    #Add-Results "TESTING"
    Write-Host "TESTING"
}
```

and I get "TESTNG".

***Some context you have not included applies, without it the only answer you will get is: it looks OK***

Comment: Wow. I dont have any idea what could it be. I look of for me too. I tested harcoding $result too. How could I troubleshoot ths issues?

Comment: @RicardoPolo Use ISE's debugger. Especially the value of `$result`.